# Как правильно организовать оформление заказа при онлайн оплате?

Tags: php, интернет-магазин

Обычно клиент просто нажимает "оформить заказ" и он создается, отображается страница успеха заказа.

Но в случае онлайн оплаты должно быть по-другому - сначала нам нужно получить ответ от стороннего сервиса об успешной оплате. Получается, заказ создавать пока рано, потому что в случае неуспешной оплаты (или просто отмены и возврата на сайт) должна остаться невредимой корзина и все данные о планируемом заказе.

Ответ от стороннего сервиса всегда присылает id заказа - чтобы проставить ему данные об успешной оплате. Но как тогда на этот id опираться, если фактически заказ еще не создан, а сессия текущего пользователя при запросе с другого сервера (сервиса оплаты) будет недоступна?

В случае, если создавать промежуточные заказы в базе данных будет проблема дублей заказов - часть будет оплачена успешно, а часть - нет, в зависимости от количества попыток заказа.

Answer (score 0):

Неплохим решений будет ввести состояния для заказа.

Созданному, но неоплаченному заказу выставляется состояние "неоплачен" (например 'await_payment' в базе), в случае срыва оплаты заказ так и остается в этом состоянии. Можно добавить автоматическое очищение заказов в таком состоянии по истечению, например, месяца. К корзине, при этом, заказ уже никакого отношения не имеет, поскольку создан. Если оплата прошла, заказ переходит в состояние "оплачен". Далее - идет по своему воркфлоу. Например, появляется состояние "отгружен", "доставляется", "получен".

Дальнейшим развитием может быть внедрение FSM (конечного автомата), тогда в принципе все переходы по состояниям будут идти через единый механизм, плюс на каждом переходе можно будет совершать какие-то действия (например, отправлять емейлы)

Comment: Да, это логично. Но как же быть с моментом, когда заказ и в базе лежит со статусом "ждет оплаты", и из сессии не удален еще - клиент может легко повторить попытку заказа, тем самым создавая дубли. А главное - после всё таки успешной оплаты каким образом со 100% уверенностью можно очистить сессию пользователя?

Comment: Я не видел магазинов, у которых при формировании заказа товары оставались бы в корзине. Обычно после нажатия кнопки "Оформить заказ" корзина очищается. Тем более, что оплата заказа может быть через длительное время, когда сессия уже "протухла". Если же нахождение товаров в корзине после заказа - обязательное бизнес-условие, лучше реализовать его кнопкой "Повторить заказ", по нажатию на которую все товары из заказа помещаются в корзину. И продублировать кнопкой "Отменить заказ" для неоплаченных